# are spring proxy calls also synchronized if the target class methods are synchronized?

Tags: java, spring, synchronization

I'm using spring transactions and one of my service classes methods need to be synchronized like below.

```
package com.xyz.service;
class  XYZService{
  public  synchronized void methodA{
   }

  public  synchronized void methodB{
   }
}
```

and I applied spring txns to my service classes like below

```
<aop:config>
        <aop:advisor id="serviceTx" advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut="execution(* *..service.*Manager.*(..)) order="0"/>
    </aop:config>

<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="*"/>
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>

<bean id="xyzManager" class="com.xyz.service.XYZService">
           </bean>
```

So when i call methodA or methodB on spring bean(xyzManager), is it still a synchronized call? Please help me..

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer is "Yes". 
Spring creates "container" and doesn't touch original signature of method.

Comment: then my doubt  is the method after proxy applied also synchronized..?
let us assume that `methodA` is proxied and become `proxy@metodA` then  `proxy@metodA` is also synchronized because of that mehtodA is synchronized ....